# How to view the data in RecycleView?

Tags: android

I use retrofit2 to import data from each of the three tables.

Put the values in one list and show them in RecycleView.

But it shows the first result from the second run.

The second result shows from the third run.

The first run is nothing.

In the first run, Adapter's list.size() also gives zero.

I don't know why.

It's MainActivity.

```
public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView foodTextView, companyTextView, dateTextView, useMaterialTextView;
    private ImageView dateChangeImgView;
    Calendar calendar;
    RecyclerView historyRecyclerView;
    ApiInterface apiInterface;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    List<CowInfoData> cowInfoDataList;
    List<RiceInfoData> riceInfoDataList;
    List<VegetableInfoData> vegetableInfoDataList;
    List list = new ArrayList();
    HistoryAdapter historyAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

        HistoryActivityInit();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String foodName = intent.getExtras().getString("food_name");
        String companyName = intent.getExtras().getString("company_name");

        foodTextView.setText(foodName);
        companyTextView.setText(companyName);
    }

    private void HistoryActivityInit() {
        foodTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_food_name);
        companyTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_company_name);
        dateChangeImgView = findViewById(R.id.imgview_date_change);
        dateTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_date);
        useMaterialTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_use_material);
        historyRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_history);

        calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

//        dateTextView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(calendar.getTime()));

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        historyRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        historyRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.imgview_date_change:
                chooseDate();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void chooseDate() {
        final View dialogView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dialog_date_picker, null);
        final DatePicker datePicker = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
        datePicker.updateDate(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", (dialog, which) -> {
            calendar = new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
            dateTextView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(calendar.getTime()));

            String f_name = foodTextView.getText().toString();
            String c_name = companyTextView.getText().toString();
            String d_date = dateTextView.getText().toString();

            Log.e("HistoryActivity", f_name);
            Log.e("HistoryActivity", c_name);
            Log.e("HistoryActivity", d_date);

            historyInquiry(f_name, c_name, d_date);
        });

        builder.show();
    }

    private void historyInquiry(String food_name, String company_name, String date) {
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<List<CowInfoData>> call = apiInterface.getHistory_cow(food_name, company_name, date);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<CowInfoData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CowInfoData>> call, Response<List<CowInfoData>> response) {
                cowInfoDataList = response.body();
                list.addAll(cowInfoDataList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CowInfoData>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ErrorMessage", t.toString());
            }
        });

        Call<List<RiceInfoData>> call2 = apiInterface.getHistory_rice(food_name, company_name, date);
        call2.enqueue(new Callback<List<RiceInfoData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<RiceInfoData>> call, Response<List<RiceInfoData>> response) {
                riceInfoDataList = response.body();
                list.addAll(riceInfoDataList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<RiceInfoData>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ErrorMessage", t.toString());
            }
        });

        Call<List<VegetableInfoData>> call3 = apiInterface.getHistory_vegetable(food_name, company_name, date);
        call3.enqueue(new Callback<List<VegetableInfoData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<VegetableInfoData>> call, Response<List<VegetableInfoData>> response) {
                vegetableInfoDataList = response.body();
                list.addAll(vegetableInfoDataList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<VegetableInfoData>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ErrorMessage", t.toString());
            }
        });

        historyAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(list, HistoryActivity.this);
        historyRecyclerView.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
        historyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

It's Adapter.

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List list;
    private Context context;

    public HistoryAdapter(List list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(list.get(position) instanceof CowInfoData) {
            return 0;
        } else if(list.get(position) instanceof RiceInfoData) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 2;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == 0) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_history_cow, parent, false);
            CowHistoryViewHolder holder = new CowHistoryViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        } else if(viewType == 1) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_history_rice, parent, false);
            RiceHistoryViewHolder holder = new RiceHistoryViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_history_vegetable, parent, false);
            VegetableHistoryViewHolder holder = new VegetableHistoryViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        if(this.getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
            CowInfoData cowInfoData = (CowInfoData)list.get(position);
            CowHistoryViewHolder holder = (CowHistoryViewHolder) viewHolder;
            holder.cowCategoryTextView.setText(cowInfoData.getCow_category());
            holder.cowCompanyTextView.setText(cowInfoData.getCow_packing_company());
            holder.cowTrackingNumTextView.setText(cowInfoData.getCow_tracking_num());
            holder.cowGradeTextView.setText(cowInfoData.getCow_grade());

            Log.e("HistoryAdapter", cowInfoData.getCow_tracking_num());
        } else if(this.getItemViewType(position) == 1) {
            RiceInfoData riceInfoData = (RiceInfoData)list.get(position);
            RiceHistoryViewHolder holder = (RiceHistoryViewHolder) viewHolder;
            holder.riceNameTextView.setText(riceInfoData.getRice_name());
            holder.riceCompanyTextView.setText(riceInfoData.getRice_company());
            holder.riceProduceTextView.setText(riceInfoData.getProduce_date());

            Log.e("HistoryAdapter", riceInfoData.getRice_name());
        } else if(this.getItemViewType(position) == 2) {
            VegetableInfoData vegetableInfoData = (VegetableInfoData)list.get(position);
            VegetableHistoryViewHolder holder = (VegetableHistoryViewHolder) viewHolder;
            holder.vegetableNameTextView.setText(vegetableInfoData.getVegetable_name());
            holder.vegetableCompanyTextView.setText(vegetableInfoData.getVegetable_company());

            Log.e("HistoryAdapter", vegetableInfoData.getVegetable_name());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.e("HistoryAdapter", String.valueOf(list.size()));
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class CowHistoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView cowCategoryTextView, cowCompanyTextView, cowTrackingNumTextView, cowGradeTextView;

        public CowHistoryViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cowCategoryTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_cow_category);
            cowCompanyTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_cow_company);
            cowTrackingNumTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_cow_tracking_num);
            cowGradeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_cow_grade);
        }
    }

    public static class RiceHistoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView riceNameTextView, riceCompanyTextView, riceProduceTextView;

        public RiceHistoryViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            riceNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_rice_name);
            riceCompanyTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_rice_company);
            riceProduceTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_rice_produce);
        }
    }

    public static class VegetableHistoryViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView vegetableNameTextView, vegetableCompanyTextView;

        public VegetableHistoryViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            vegetableNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_vegetable_name);
            vegetableCompanyTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_vegetable_company);
        }
    }
}
```

Plz Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` after updating data

just add `historyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`  after  `list.addAll(cowInfoDataList)`;

also

```
historyAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(list, HistoryActivity.this);
historyRecyclerView.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
```

These two lines should be executed before calling API. May be inside oncreate()